# How to show relation key and value model in Rails Simple Form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form, simple-form-for

In my app i have `kids` and `lessons` tables.

Kids has `id` and `name` columns. Lessons has `id` , `kid_id` , `key` an `value` columns.

Lessons `key` and `value` will keep kids lesson name and it's score.

But i don't know how to show lessons in rails `simple form` ? In my form there must be 5 lessons like math , english etc. What i want to do is like :

```
Name <input type='text' name='name' placeholder='Kid Name'>

Math <input type='text' name='key["math"]' placeholder='Score'> 

English <input type='text' name='key["english"]' placeholder='Score'>

History <input type='text' name='key["history"]' placeholder='Score'>
```

i do not know show and save this in rails simple form. 
Is it possible do use same name and do a foreach to save Lessons table in my controller ?.

Comment: I think you need https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form

Comment: let me try :) ..

Comment: Are you using `:accepts_nested_attributes_for`?

Comment: oh ok , i added it but in form what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Add gem [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) to your project and then you can do it like this:

**Controller action**

```
# Find Kid instance (or build one based on what action you are in)
@kid = Kid.find(<id>)

# Assuming you have an association `has_many :lessons` in `Kid` model, build 5 Lesson instances related to @kid
@lessons = %w[Math English History ...].each { |l| @kid.lessons.build(key: l) }
```

**View**

```
<%= form_for @kid do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :lessons do |l| %>
    <%= l.text_field :key %>
    <%= l.text_field :value %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

WARNING: The code is not tested. It only provides an idea of implementation.

Comment: how can i multiple key and value inputs ? cuz i need 5 from them.

Comment: That's why i build 5 objects. One for each lesson. See controller code.

Comment: i can't understand what will be in here : `%w[Math English History ...]` can you write it with details ?

Comment: `%w[Math English History]` is just a different but shorter way to write `["Math" "English" "History"]`.

Comment: You missed the commas @Roland Stunder. It will be `["Math", "English", "History"]`